# Will kjournald takes too much space?

Tags: filesystems

I am changing my hard disk to ext3 because journalling got so much write my server crash.

Well, now I use SSD. Journalling is no longer the issue.

But SSD are small.

Will journaling takes so much space?

kjournald writes 5MB-10MB of data all the time. However, there is no file that's bigger than 2MB.

So I wonder what it actually writes.

We don't have this in windows right?

Comment: Most modern file systems use a journal or a similar approach and NTFS does it, too.

Comment: *"We don't have this in windows right?"*  Sure?  Most things "in Windows" seem rather opaque, I couldn't tell how its journaling works from poking around...

Comment: What daemon are you running on your server ? Anything that uses a lot of Disk I/O ??
Perhaps you can install a utility called [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) and see what process is performing the most I/O.

Comment: I did. That process is called kjournald. It seems that kjournald writes way more data than real writes.

Comment: Have you apply `noatime` to `fstab` yet?

Comment: I used relatime which should be just as good. Will try noatime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filesystem  journal (which you are seeing as 5MB-10MB) is a collection of all pending changes to the filesystem and not necessarily belonging to one file.

The Journal is more like a rough changes that are pending to be written to hard disk.
By using a buffer before actual write we have an advantage to keep filesystem consistent incase of power failure  or system crash but the disadvantage is every changes to filesystem are written twice (once to the journal and second time in HardDisk )

This space is internally used by filesystem and more likely to be stored in OS memory or a fixed area instead as a file on a filesystem.

Windows NTFS  does have journaling inbuilt into it

Comment: But the number of writes are not even that much. Nothing else writes too much.